# Changing keyboard input in tkinter to alphabetical

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, keyboard

I'm making a purposefully annoying GUI that will change keyboard inputs to alphabetical order instead of QWERTY.

How could I make it so that it converts all the characters automatically when typing into a box?

Comment: Are you using a `tkinter.Text`?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```py
import tkinter as tk

REPLACE_DICT = {"q": "a",
                "w": "b",
                "e": "c",
                "r": "d",
                "t": "e",
                "y": "f"}

def keyboard_pressed(event):
    char_pressed = event.char
    if char_pressed.lower() in REPLACE_DICT:
        char = REPLACE_DICT[char_pressed.lower()]
        if char_pressed.upper() == char_pressed:
            # If uppercase:
            char = char.upper()
        # Insert the character
        event.widget.insert("insert", char)
        # Return "break" to stop the event
        return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
text_widget = tk.Text(root) # tk.Entry(root) also works
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

It binds to `"<Key>"`. When a key is pressed it replaces it with whatever is in `REPLACE_DICT`. It inserts the desired key into the widget and returns `"break"` to stop tkinter from handling that key press.

Please note I only added the first 6 keys: `q`, `w`, `e`, `r`, `t`, `y`.